# Change date by one day Datetimepicker plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I've been trying to increase / decrease the date of my input by one day for a while now but getting now where.

**See my code:**

**function**

```
function backDay() {
    var date = $('input#datetimepicker').val();

    var NewDate = moment().subtract(1, 'day');
    $('input#datetimepicker').val(NewDate);
}
```

**html**

```
<input class="form-control" style="text-align:center" type="text" id="datetimepicker" name="CurrentDay" value="{{ date('d/m/Y') }}">
```

**Button to add go back 1 day**

```
<button onclick="backDay()">Go back 1 Day</button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass `date` in `moment()` otherwise it will pick current `date`

```
function backDay() {
    var date = $('input#datetimepicker').val();
    var NewDate = moment(date).subtract(1, 'day');
    $('input#datetimepicker').val(NewDate._d);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @void this is great but at the moment i'm getting Invalid date in the input element?

Comment: @Wolrab what do you mean by date? Can you please create a JSFIDDLE?

Comment: Sorry @void I'm unfamiler with JSFIDDLE, I'm not sure how to pull in the libraries. Im using bootstrap3 datetimepicker and trying to increase the day of an input by 1

Comment: Can you tell me what is the value of your input? I mean what is the exact dat from whic h you are trying to subtract a day?

Comment: Sure, today's date in the following format 'DD/MM/YYYY'

Comment: And when you set the new value what are you seeing in the input box?

Comment: Check the updated answer. Now i am setting `NewDate._d`? Check if it works.